# postgres inner join sum for when no relation exists

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am trying to run a simple query where I get a sum of gardeners who have zero support visits. I would like to add other cases, but first I would like to get this zero thing right. This is what I have come up with:

```
Gardener.from(Gardener.joins(:support_visits).group(:gardener_id).select("CASE WHEN count(gardener_id) = 0 THEN 1 END AS zero_count"),:t).select("sum(t.zero_count) as tot_zero_count")
```

Which gives me the following sql query:

```
SELECT sum(t.zero_count) as tot_zero_count
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN count(gardener_id) = 0 THEN 1 END AS zero_count
    FROM "gardeners" INNER JOIN "support_visits"
    ON "support_visits"."gardener_id" = "gardeners"."id"
    GROUP BY gardener_id
) t
```

The query runs but gives me nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query uses `count(gardener_id) = 0` which is never true because any group will have at least one record.  Instead, you can `LEFT JOIN` the `gardeners` table to the `support_visits` table.  Any gardener which does not appear in the `support_visits` table will not match to a visit, leaving a `null` value which you can then count.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN "support_visits"."gardener_id" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS zero_count
FROM "gardeners" LEFT JOIN "support_visits"
ON "support_visits"."gardener_id" = "gardeners"."id"
```

Here is the Ruby ActiveRecord code for this query:

```
Gardener.from(Gardener.joins("LEFT JOIN `support_visits` ON gardeners.id = support_visits.gardener_id").select("SUM(CASE WHEN "support_visits"."gardener_id" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS zero_count"))
```

Comment: hmmm. sadly that's not working, getting a syntax error, can't seem to spot it.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that a gardener with no support visits will not appear in the `support_visits` table?

Comment: You are correct. It has just a gardener_id in the support visit table.

Comment: I believe the raw query I gave you to be sound, and you should test it.  I'm not too familiar with Ruby on Rails though.  Do you have code in any other place where you are doing a left join?  Can you copy and then modify such code to my answer?